# How I can use actual value which depends on date

Tags: python, pandas

I am analysing sales at marketplace and can't decide how to use a cost price, which depends on  a date when I've changed it.

For instance

1. I had received an order, item A, in 12 March  and it cost price was 100 dollars.
2. After that I changed the cost price on 10 dollars in 20 March - 110 dollars.
3. Next, I received an order , item A, in 25 March.
4. Then I constructed a report which included all sales in March.

And the order, item A, from 12 March had cost price 100 dollars. The order, item A, from 25 March had the cost price 110 dollars.

If I don't change the cost price - column price_change_date is empty , it won't change in the report and I use a value in column cost_price.

I can rebuild table cost_price if it is necessary.

My tables look like this:

Table with orders:

```
orders_test = {
    'order_id': ['82514913-0085-1', '82514913-0085-1', '82514913-0090-1', '82514913-0090-1'],
    'article_id': ['99823WH2MO11093_34', '99823WH2MO11093_34', '99823WH2MO11093_34', '99823WH2MO11093_34'],
    'profit': [1042.91, 1042.91, 2000, 2000],
    'order_date': ['01-15-2024', '01-21-2024', '02-15-2024', '02-20-2024']
}
orders_test = pd.DataFrame(orders_test)
orders_test['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(orders_test['order_date'])
```

Table with cost price:

```
cost_price_test = {
    'article_id': ['99823WH2MO11093_34', '99823WH2MO11093_34', '99823WH2MO11093_34'],
    'cost_price': [100, 110, 120],
    'price_change_date': ['01-10-2024', '01-20-2024', '02-10-2024'],
    'new_cost_price': [110, 120, 100]
}

cost_price_test = pd.DataFrame(data)
cost_price_test['price_change_date'] = pd.to_datetime(cost_price_test['price_change_date'])
```

The desired result is as follows:

```
          order_id          article_id   profit order_date  cost_price
0  82514913-0085-1  99823WH2MO11093_34  1042.91 01-15-2024         100
1  82514913-0085-2  99823WH2MO11093_34  1042.91 01-21-2024         120
2  82514913-0090-3  99823WH2MO11093_34  2000.00 02-15-2024         100
3  82514913-0090-4  99823WH2MO11093_34  2000.00 02-20-2024         100
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: How does the order at 2-15-2024 get 120? and the order at 2-20-2024 get 110?

Comment: @ScottBoston Yeah, you are right! It's my mistake! Sorry for this! Order 2-15-2024 and 2-20-24 must be with 100

Answer (score 0):

I believe the values in your initial example are wrong, particularly on column `order_id`, as they are different from the ones in your expected result. Besides, the values on column `cost_price` of your expected result don't seem to follow the logic you described.

IIUC, and assuming these dataframes initially:

```
orders_test:
          order_id          article_id   profit order_date
0  82514913-0085-1  99823WH2MO11093_34  1042.91 2024-01-15
1  82514913-0085-2  99823WH2MO11093_34  1042.91 2024-01-21
2  82514913-0090-3  99823WH2MO11093_34  2000.00 2024-02-15
3  82514913-0090-4  99823WH2MO11093_34  2000.00 2024-02-20

cost_price_test:
           article_id  cost_price price_change_date  new_cost_price
0  99823WH2MO11093_34         100        2024-01-10             110
1  99823WH2MO11093_34         110        2024-01-20             120
2  99823WH2MO11093_34         120        2024-02-10             100
```

You can follow this approach:

0. Optional in case `cost_price_test` has null values for column `new_cost_price`: fill null values with column `cost_price`;
1. Merge the dataframes with `how='left'`;
2. Sort by `order_date`;
3. Remove rows where `order_date` is earlier than `price_date_change`;
4. Remove duplicate rows based on `order_id` and `article_id`, keeping the last row, seeing as they are sorted by `order_date`.

```
cost_price_test["new_cost_price"] = cost_price_test["new_cost_price"].fillna(
    cost_price_test["cost_price"]
)

orders_test = pd.merge(orders_test, cost_price_test, how="left").sort_values(
    "order_date"
)
orders_test = orders_test.loc[
    orders_test["order_date"] >= orders_test["price_change_date"]
].drop_duplicates(["order_id", "article_id"], keep="last")
orders_test = orders_test.drop(columns=["cost_price", "price_change_date"]).rename(
    columns={"new_cost_price": "cost_price"}
)
```

The result will be:

```
           order_id          article_id   profit order_date  cost_price
0   82514913-0085-1  99823WH2MO11093_34  1042.91 2024-01-15         110
4   82514913-0085-2  99823WH2MO11093_34  1042.91 2024-01-21         120
8   82514913-0090-3  99823WH2MO11093_34  2000.00 2024-02-15         100
11  82514913-0090-4  99823WH2MO11093_34  2000.00 2024-02-20         100
```

Comment: Could you help me in this - when I'm trying to use part of your decision. 

After this I lose rows. My data frame before it had 1021 rows, after 944.

orders_test = orders_test.loc[orders_test["order_date"] >= orders_test["price_change_date"]
].drop_duplicates(["order_id", "article_id"], keep="last")

How can I avoid it? Please!

p.s I don't know how can I show you on real data, real situation - sorry, I'm juniour in it

Comment: You have duplicate rows for values order_id and article_id. You could instead drop duplicates by index. I won't have access to a computer for a while, but you can easily search how to do that. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I've done it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.merge_asof` like this:

```
merged_df = pd.merge_asof(orders_test, 
                          cost_price_test, 
                          left_on='order_date', 
                          right_on='price_change_date', 
                          direction='backward', suffixes=('', '_y'))
```

Then select the correct price based on dates:

```
merged_df['new_cost'] = np.where(merged_df['order_date']<=merged_df['price_change_date'], 
                                 merged_df['cost_price'], 
                                 merged_df['new_cost_price'])
```

Output:

```
          order_id          article_id   profit order_date        article_id_y  cost_price price_change_date  new_cost_price  new_cost
0  82514913-0085-1  99823WH2MO11093_34  1042.91 2024-01-15  99823WH2MO11093_34         100        2024-01-10             110       110
1  82514913-0085-1  99823WH2MO11093_34  1042.91 2024-01-21  99823WH2MO11093_34         110        2024-01-20             120       120
2  82514913-0090-1  99823WH2MO11093_34  2000.00 2024-02-15  99823WH2MO11093_34         120        2024-02-10             100       100
3  82514913-0090-1  99823WH2MO11093_34  2000.00 2024-02-20  99823WH2MO11093_34         120        2024-02-10             100       100
```

Lastly you can column filter this dataframe to only show the columns you want.

```
merged_df[['order_id', 'article_id', 'profit', 'order_date', 'new_cost']]
```

Output:

```
          order_id          article_id   profit order_date  new_cost
0  82514913-0085-1  99823WH2MO11093_34  1042.91 2024-01-15       110
1  82514913-0085-1  99823WH2MO11093_34  1042.91 2024-01-21       120
2  82514913-0090-1  99823WH2MO11093_34  2000.00 2024-02-15       100
3  82514913-0090-1  99823WH2MO11093_34  2000.00 2024-02-20       100
```

Comment: thanks! I've seen new way to solve it! Thanks for knowledge!